# How to query a model based on multiple associated models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I have a rails application where I have following models -

City, Hotel, Restaurant, Park.

Associations are like this -

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :hotels
 has_many :restaurants
 has_many :parks

end
```

I want to find all cities that have at least one hotel or restaurant or Park.

How do I write single query to fetch such cities ?

Comment: You need to mention your model relationships in the question

Comment: Right. I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5, you can use like below

```
cities = City.includes(:hotels, :restaurants, :parks)
cities = ((cities.where.not(hotels: {id: nil})).or(cities.where.not(restaurants: {id: nil})).or(cities.where.not(parks: {id: nil})))
```

For lower version of rails , you need to use arel_table

Answer (score 0):

The City model doesn't have any information about related stuff.
You need to select the data from hotel/park/etc.

Use AR's `includes` to find the all Cities with specified relations.

`City.includes(:hotels, :restaurants, :parks)`

Answer (score 0):

Most appropriate solution would be using [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

Then you should be able to query like

`City.where('hotels_count > 0 OR restaurants_count > 0 OR parks_count > 0')`

P.S. This query can be re-written many ways e.g use `.or` method. Also, don't forget to reset cache counter if you have some data in associated tables.